# spring boot security login redirects to / when contextPath set

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot

I've got this working when no contextPath is set. But when I set server.contextPath in application.properties, happens that when logging in http://localhost:8080/t2debt_site/login the page redirects to http://localhost:8080/login. What can be happening, please help!

```
private static final String[] UNSECURED_RESOURCE_LIST =
        new String[]{"/", "/resources/**", "/static/**", "/css/**", "/webjars/**",
                "/img/**", "/js/**"};

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(UNSECURED_RESOURCE_LIST).permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/index")
            .failureUrl("/login?error")
            .usernameParameter("email")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutUrl("/logout")
            .deleteCookies("remember-me")
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .rememberMe();
}

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity security) {
    //security.ignoring().antMatchers("/css/**","/img/**","/js/**");
    //security.ignoring().antMatchers("/static/**");
    security.ignoring().antMatchers(UNSECURED_RESOURCE_LIST);
    //security.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**");
}
```